# How to fix Intel Corporation: Unknown on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, wireless, intel, dkms, additional-drivers

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. When I open Software & Updates on the *Additional Drivers* tab there is `Intel Corporation: Unknown This device is not working`.

[image]

My wifi is normally working, but the signal is poor. I can't get a full signal, even if the computer is close to the router.

I can't choose *Continue using a manually installed driver*. Is there a way to make this device work?

Comment: here is the SS
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaoCp.png

Comment: @karel my wifi is normally working, but the signal is poor, can't achieve full signal, even it's so close with the router